# QML chart axis label

Tags: qt, qml

I'm developing a line chart using QML with qt creator and
I'd like to add a character appended to every axis label: example I want to display °C appended to the numeber 15 which is on the axis x (final result: 15°C).

I tried using this QML code

```
ValueAxis {
min: 0;
max: 100;
labelFormat: "%d%1".arg("°C)
}
```

The result is 15?C.

Does someone help me to solve this problem?
Many thanks in advance!

Comment: What a sense to use `arg()` here? Why not just `"%d%1 °C"`? Did you try to replace Celsius sigh with `\370` or `\u2103` or `&deg;`? Or, maybe with `\xB0` (ASCII symbol).

Comment: I used "&deg" and the symbol ° is displayed correctly, but when I append C, the symbol is replace with &deg.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [QML example](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtcharts-qmlweather-example.html)

```
ValueAxis {
  min: 0;
  max: 100;
  labelFormat: "%d&deg;C" // this formats label as 1°C
}
```